# Inserting Records

Tags: php, html, mysql

I can't insert the records for billing information. I have no idea why. SQL query looks good.

I don't see any error. That's why I don't have any idea whats happening.

What can I do to fix this?

```html
 
 
  <?php
 include("includes/db1.php");
 include("includes/functions1.php");
 
 error_reporting(E_ERROR);
 if($_REQUEST['command']=='update'){
  $name=$_REQUEST['name'];
  $email=$_REQUEST['email'];
  $address=$_REQUEST['address'];
  $phone=$_REQUEST['phone'];
  
  $result=mysql_query("insert into customers (name,email,phone,address,date,status) values('$name','$email','$phone','$address','Pending')");
  $customerid=mysql_insert_id();
  $date=date('Y-m-d');
  $result=mysql_query("insert into orders values('','$date','$customerid')");
  $orderid=mysql_insert_id();
  
  $max=count($_SESSION['cart']);
  for($i=0;$i<$max;$i++){
   $pid=$_SESSION['cart'][$i]['id'];
   $q=$_SESSION['cart'][$i]['qty'];
   $price=get_price($pid);
   mysql_query("insert into order_detail values ($orderid,$pid,$q,$price)");
  }
  die('Thank You! your order has been placed! <a href="customer.php">go home</a>');
 }
?>
<br> 
    </div>
<form name="form1" onsubmit="return validate()">
    <input type="hidden" name="command" />
 <div align="center">
        <h1 align="center">Billing Info</h1>
        <table border="0" cellpadding="2px">
            <tr><td>Your Name:</td><td><input type="text" name="name" required/></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Address:</td><td><input type="text" name="address" required/></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Email:</td><td><input type="text" name="email" required/></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Phone:</td><td><input type="text" name="phone" required/></td></tr>
            <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td><input type="submit" value="Place Order" /></td></tr>
        </table>
 </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I would recommend that when doing inserts - always list the columns your inserting into.  This may be the problem with your orders table if it has an auto increment key.

Comment: remove line command = "update". and write if(isset("command")) .

Comment: `php.ini` `display_error` is `on` or `off`?

Comment: have you tried removing single quote around "values" variables?

Comment: NB: `mysql_*` functions are deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this **mysql_error()** you will get the error that needs to be resolved

```
 $result=mysql_query("insert into customers (name,email,phone,address,date,status) values('$name','$email','$phone','$address','Pending')") or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd start with using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). This helps in understanding your queries (i.m.o) and is a must from security perspective (never, never trust user input).

Your code would look something like when using the prepared statements:

*dbconnection.php*:

```
<?php
  define("Servername", "192.168.1.11"); // ip of the db server
  define('Username', 'john'); // the username to authenticate to the db server
  define('Password', '40cb6fc6bd8e760d23f257c'); // the password for authentication
  define('DBname', 'my db'); // the database to use.

  function getconn(){
    $conn = new mysqli(Servername, Username, Password, DBname);
  }
?>
```

*main.php*:

```
<?php
  include("dbconnection.php");
  $conn = getconn();      

  if($_REQUEST["command"]=="update"){
    $name=$_REQUEST["name"];
    $email=$_REQUEST["email"];
    $address=$_REQUEST["address"];
    $phone=$_REQUEST["phone"];

    // Create the customer.
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("insert into customers (name,email,phone,address,date,status) values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("ssssss", $name, $email, $phone, $address, $status);
    $status = "Pending";
    $stmt->execute();     
    $customerid=$stmt->insert_id;
    $date=date('Y-m-d');
    $stmt->close();

    // Create the order
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("insert into orders (col2, col3) values (?, ?);");
    $stmt->bind_param("si", $date, $customerid);
    $stmt->execute();
    $orderid = $stmt->insert_id;
    $stmt->close(); 

    // create the order details
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("insert into order_detail (col1, col2, col3, col4) values (?, ?, ?, ?)($orderid,$pid,$q,$price)")
    $stmt->bind_param("isss", $orderid, $pid, $q, $price);
    for($i=0; $i < count($_SESSION['cart']); $i++){
        $pid=$_SESSION['cart'][$i]['id'];
        $q=$_SESSION['cart'][$i]['qty'];
        $price=get_price($pid);
        $stmt->execute();
    }
    // clean up after yourself.
    $stmt->close();
    $conn->close();
    die('Thank You! your order has been placed! <a href="customer.php">go home</a>');
  }
?>
```

*in the above code you will need to define the colx's to the corresponding column names*

I found that code build like this will give you an good clue what is wrong when it doesn't work. Look into your web server's (apache2/nginx/etc) error.log to find out what if it happens.

Beside using prepared statements you should look into [input validation](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_form_validation.asp).